# Need to check if a session cookie is being denied

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a situation where an iframe is setting a cookie, for a facebook app. The problem we are facing is that in IE you can disable third party cookies which breaks prevents the session cookie from being set, which breaks the app.

If anyone has a solution that will allow us to keep using a session cookie in this situation or perhaps a coding solution to detect whether cookies are accepted or not, that would be great!

Comment: your server could not do anything to detect a 3rd party cookie, because the client browser would never send that 3rd part cookie along with the requests. That'd violate cookie security outright. You'd need client-side code, and hope that the cookie's not been set to http-only.

Comment: If I rely on javascript I leave myself open to folks without javascript enabled. I'd prefer to do this with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["CHECKCOOKIE"]))
{
    // Check for cookie request
    if (isset($_REQUEST["COOKIECHECK"]))
    {
        // Error
        die("ERROR");
    }

    // Set the check cookie
    setcookie("CHECKCOOKIE", "YES");

    // Redirect back to itself
    header("location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "?COOKIECHECK");
}
```